# I can't solve this Fatal error problem with pdfMerger

Tags: php, pdf

I'm trying to merge some pdf's, but I have a problem that I can't understand and I don't know what's happening, Can someone help me?

Attached code in `PHP`

This is the method for `pdfMerger`

```
public static function pdfMerger($archivos, $destino){
            $pdf = new PDFMerger(); // or use $pdf = new \PDFMerger; for Laravel
            if($archivos != null){
                for($i=0; $i < count($archivos); $i++){
                    $pdf->addPDF($archivos[$i], 'all');
                }
            }
            $pdf->merge('file', $destino);
        }
```

And here is where I'm calling the method:

```
//This is a test
$control = new FilesController();
    $dir = "/Jomar/induccion/documents/";
    $files = glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."{$dir}politicas empresa/*.pdf");
    $url = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."{$dir}politicas empresa/prueba.pdf";
    print_r($files);
    $control->pdfMerger($files, $url);
```

This is the error I'm currently receiving:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: TCPDF_PARSER ERROR: decodeFilterFlateDecode: invalid code in C:\xampp\htdocs\Jomar\induccion\config\PDFMerger-master\tcpdf\include\tcpdf_filters.php:474 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Jomar\induccion\config\PDFMerger-master\tcpdf\include\tcpdf_filters.php(359): TCPDF_FILTERS::Error('decodeFilterFla...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Jomar\induccion\config\PDFMerger-master\tcpdf\include\tcpdf_filters.php(94): TCPDF_FILTERS::decodeFilterFlateDecode('\xEA\x91\xB9mj/\xAB\x8E;iN\xA3\x143\xAF...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Jomar\induccion\config\PDFMerger-master\tcpdf\tcpdi_parser.php(1310): TCPDF_FILTERS::decodeFilter('FlateDecode', '\xEA\x91\xB9mj/\xAB\x8E;iN\xA3\x143\xAF...') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\Jomar\induccion\config\PDFMerger-master\tcpdf\tcpdi_parser.php(1249): tcpdi_parser->_rebuildContentStream(Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\Jomar\induccion\config\PDFMerger-master\tcpdf\tcpdi.php(192): tcpdi_parser->getContent() #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\Jomar\induccion\config\PDFMerger-master\PDFMerger.php(104): TCPDI->importPage(1) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Jomar\induccion\config\PDFMerger-master\tcpdf\include\tcpdf_filters.php on line 474

(Sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was of the permissions of the pdf, therefore, is necessary to check that in the pdf document doesn't have any type of restrictions. thanks for your help.